# AJAX/jQuery - populate HTML alternate method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm researching alternate methods for loading data from a PHP script with AJAX/jQuery but an having trouble either A)Refining my question well enough or B)Finding any documentation.

Currently, I use regular post class with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'script.php',
  data: {
          data1: $('#input1').val(),
          data2: $('#input2').val()
        },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
             $.each(data, function (key, value){
               $('#data-cont').append(value);
             });
           }
 })
```

Where `script.php` returns json data.

Now, where I have `$('#data-cont').append(value);` is typically a HUGE mess where I try and insert response data along side HTML mark up.  It's super ugly, and really a pain to sort through and build.

In doing research, I've seen `dataType: 'html'`, which parses the html for data by element ID.  Personally, I think producing HTML with PHP is a lot easier and cleaner than with jquery/javascript. Where with PHP, you can use alternate syntax with `if` statements and such, producing cleaner code and markup which is easier to organize and develop.

So, to my actual question.

For compiling data into HTML markup, which is standard/more preferred script response, HTML or JSON  build markup in jQuery/js?

Comment: Could you add what kind of output you are expecting, and what output you are currently getting?

Comment: Any code I have works, I'm just looking for which is better practice for building/displaying HTML: Receiving JSON/Building HTML client side VS Building HTML Server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It honestly depends on what you need to do client side with that response.

If it is simply something that needs to be displayed, go ahead and generate the html server side and just add it to the dom where you see fit.

When you would want to return json would be if you needed to make decisions client side based on that data.

For a very simple example, you have a json structure returned that contains a list of clients from a database, and this json also includes each clients Primary Key and phone number for instance. Now you can create a object that holds that json data, handles building a list for display, and binds a onclick method to each list item. Now when the user clicks on a list item, you can simply return the index of that list item, which will correspond to the same index in your json data structure, and now instead of having to parse html attributes for more data about that list item/client, you have direct access to your json data structure, without another server request or messing javascript. You could in the onclick add the clients primary key to another array which would store who should be contacted etc. Then you could provide a submit button which would pass the primary keys back to the server to do logic for some service to the user (making it so you wouldn't have to resolve a client by first name and last name).

It's really all about the task at hand, rather than a "proper" or "best" way to do it.

But it is worth mentioning, why do on the server, what you could do client side? You save resources by making communications light. JSON is very light.

And another note, for SEO you should almost always build all your HTML server-side.

Comment: AJAX request receives JSON data and then builds HTML.  For server efficiency, I understand/agree with letting client side scripts parse the data and build the HTML.